# Why isn't systemd restarting simple service that has Restart=always after main process killed?

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I created a simple systemd service `test.service` with `Restart=always`

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/home/core/test.sh
```

and `test.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

sleep 1h
```

After `systemctl start test.service` and `systemctl status test.servce`, it shows `test.sh` main process and `sleep` sub process.

```
● test.service - test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; linked; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-06 12:53:51 CST; 2s ago
   Main PID: 2032464 (bash)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 127633)
     Memory: 736.0K
        CPU: 4ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
             ├─2032464 bash /home/core/test.sh
             └─2032465 sleep 1h
```

And then kill `test.sh` via `sudo kill 2032464` and do a `systemctl status test.servce` again, main process killed while `sleep` sub process exists.

```
● test.service - test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; linked; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-06 12:53:51 CST; 9s ago
    Process: 2032464 ExecStart=/home/core/test.sh (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 2032464 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 127633)
     Memory: 204.0K
        CPU: 4ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
             └─2032465 sleep 1h
```

Why systemd does not restart `test.service` on main process killed?

### OS Environment

```
NAME="Flatcar Container Linux by Kinvolk"
ID=flatcar
ID_LIKE=coreos
VERSION=3510.2.6
VERSION_ID=3510.2.6
BUILD_ID=2023-08-07-1638
SYSEXT_LEVEL=1.0
PRETTY_NAME="Flatcar Container Linux by Kinvolk 3510.2.6 (Oklo)"
ANSI_COLOR="38;5;75"
HOME_URL="https://flatcar.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://issues.flatcar.org"
FLATCAR_BOARD="amd64-usr"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:flatcar-linux:flatcar_linux:3510.2.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
```

### Systemd Version

```
systemd 252 (252)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX -APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL -ACL +BLKID +CURL -ELFUTILS -FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE -TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
```

Comment: In my Kubuntu I can replicate your result with [`ExitType=cgroup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExitType=). According to the documentation the default is `main` though. What if you explicitly specify `ExitType=main`?

Comment: Explicitly specify `ExitType=main`, systemd still not auto restart the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by new flatcar linux container version (3510.2.7)

[Containerd not restarting properly after upgrade to systemd 252.11 on stable](https://github.com/flatcar/Flatcar/issues/1157)